# swap lines and add TAB on Excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've the source below:

```
1   PK5291  09:32:28:17 00:00:40:00         00:00:00:00 00:00:40:00
```

and I want to convert it the template below:

```
PK5291  N   C   2020/02/27 09:32:28 D   00:01:00:00 0   N   N
```

when the space between `PK5291` to `N` is a <kbd>TAB</kbd>

I tried the formula below without success, where is my mistake?

```
=CONCATENATE(B8,CHAR(9),"N","CHAR(9)","C","CHAR(9)","2020/03/08 C8","CHAR(9)","D","CHAR(9)",D8,"CHAR(9)",0,"CHAR(9)","N","CHAR(9)","N")
```

Comment: "without success" - what that exactly mean?

Comment: this is what I get from formula: =CONCATENATE(B8,CHAR(9),"N","CHAR(9)","C","CHAR(9)","2020/03/08 C8","CHAR(9)","D","CHAR(9)",D8,"CHAR(9)",0,"CHAR(9)","N","CHAR(9)","N")    but not the result that i should get like after B8-->TAB-->then insert N-->TAB....

Comment: Im not sure i fully understand but does this do what you want? `=B8&" N C "&"2020/02/27" & " " & LEFT(C8,8) & " D " & D8 & " 0 N N"`

Comment: can you please e-mail me so I can add the original file and what i converted manually so you can see what i mean? i don't success to load file here... xtxtxtxt@gmail.com

Comment: Questions asked on Superuser should be complete, and not require resources that won't be available to anyone who reads them in the futue. Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1531202/edit) to add more information. If needed, you can upload files to http://imgur.com and link to them here

Comment: 1. Anything you put inside `""` in a `CONCATENATE` will show up as text, so `CONCATENATE(...,"CHAR(9)",...)` is not going to insert a <kbd>TAB</kbd> into your cell. 2. I don't think you can insert <kbd>TAB</kbd> into cell text in Excel anyway. Try it yourself with `="test"&CHAR(9)&"here"` in a formula bar. It will return "testhere". Does it actually need to be a <kbd>TAB</kbd>? Why? I'd suggest that you tell us what you're actually trying to do, include all relevant details, and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: there is progress... but have a liitle issue... this is the formula that I use =CONCAT(B8,CHAR(9),"N",CHAR(9),"C",CHAR(9),K5,"",C8,CHAR(9),"D",CHAR(9),D8,CHAR(9),"0",CHAR(9),"N",CHAR(9),"N")=CONCAT(B8,CHAR(9),"N",CHAR(9),"C",CHAR(9),K5,"",C8,CHAR(9),"D",CHAR(9),D8,CHAR(9),"0",CHAR(9),"N",CHAR(9),"N") and this is the text for this formula:"PK5321 N C 2020/03/0906:17:32:10 D 00:00:25:00 0 N N"     when i save it as text i get: "PK5321 N C 2020/03/0906:17:32:10 D 00:00:25:00 0 N N"   My question is how to remove the " from begining and end?